# How to resize 2 divs with VerticalBar in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I found one solution but it is used jQuery `Reference.html` and the directive code is like:

```
angular.module('mc.resizer', []).directive('resizer', function($document) {

    return function($scope, $element, $attrs) {

        $element.on('mousedown', function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();

            $document.on('mousemove', mousemove);
            $document.on('mouseup', mouseup);
        });

        .....
    };
});
```

Comment: can you explain the outcome that you are expecting

Comment: i want to resize two div contents with vertical dragbar.if i drag verical bar to left then left content size should be decrease and right content size should be increased. i send one plunker example link but it is internally used jQuery reference but i want only in angularjs. the link is   'http://plnkr.co/edit/Zi2f0EPxmtEUmdoFR63B?p=preview'.

Comment: You are probably trying to do what has already been done in [angular range slider](https://www.google.co.kr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwilzvKOy8HJAhUEjJQKHVajCkoQFggbMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Fdanielcrisp%2Fangular-rangeslider&usg=AFQjCNGJiNOWaSM_xKnkPF8DPLPUwHgrIQ&sig2=UPAj76xRIqU6MEbKwNci6g)

Comment: no, slider is different from what i expected

Answer (score 0):

Replace the jQuery

```
$($attrs.resizerLeft).css({
    width: x + 'px'
});
$($attrs.resizerRight).css({
    left: (x + parseInt($attrs.resizerWidth)) + 'px'
});
```

With the AngularJS equivalent

```
var rLeftElem = $document[0].getElementById($attrs.resizerLeft);
var rRightElem = $document[0].getElementById($attrs.resizerRight);

angular.element(rLeftElem).css({
    width: x + 'px'
});
angular.element(rRightElem).css({
    left: (x + parseInt($attrs.resizerWidth)) + 'px'
});
```

Tedious, but it can be done.

For more information see the [AngularJS jqLite API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element).