# How to Resize multiple div contents with vertical drag bars in only angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

here i got on example but in this we are able to resize only one div content but 
  i need to resize more than one div contents. the plunker url is

http://embed.plnkr.co/ubWb5DbFeOqwsQ7fqs9j/

Comment: So what is the problem? What is stopping you from resizing more than one div?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to resize 2 divs with VerticalBar in AngularJS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34081876/how-to-resize-2-divs-with-verticalbar-in-angularjs)